# .NET driver for MongoDb: Is any way to avoid property names hardcoding?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I can use `collection.Insert<T>` for inserting instances and `collection.Save<T>` to update them, and I see no reasons why MongoDb's c# driver does not provide similar method to remove specific instance. Their `Remove` method asks for IMongoQuery argument which seems to require hardcoding property names like `Query.EQ("Id", BsonValue.Create(id))`. I'd like to specify whole instance to delete it like `Remove<T>`, or having RemoveById, or build LINQ-like query with specific input type, or any other way to get rid of property hard-coding, - the things I get used in MS Entity Framework POCO. Is any such a way?

UPDATE: Ok, I've found one way to do it:

```
IMongoQuery mq = new QueryDocument(entity.ToBsonDocument());
customers.Remove(mq);
```

is it the only way?

Thanks

Comment: However, I don't really see how you can template this thing, because ID is such a specific thing. How would you specify the ID if you use a template function?

Comment: I put Id as an example, the question is wider: is any way to specify entity for Remove operation not hardcoding its property names? One of the way might be to specify reference to the entity, other way is to specify Id value, not its name (equal to the method collection.FindOneById()), ideally I would be glad to have LINQ-like method Remove(entity => entity.Id == 1). Anyway I hate hardcoding database attributes names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not yet a way to do what you are asking for but it is a frequently asked for feature. You can vote for the feature on this JIRA request:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-457

The approach you found works but is rather heavy handed. It is using the entire document as a query. Yes, it does match the document you are trying to Remove, but there's more data travelling over the wire than necessary.

Comment: You are right, it's an heavy operation. Other than excessive data transfer, it serializes entity object (ToBsonDocument() does it). It's Ok for one-time operation, but might be critical for performance in case of multiple run in a loop.